# URL(filePath: strPath) vs URL(fileURLWithPath: strPath)

Tags: swift, overloading

```
let url = URL(filePath: pathString!)
let url2 = URL(fileURLWithPath: pathString!)
```

I tried both and they worked both.

**What's the difference between the two ways creating such an URL-object?**

Comment: The second one seems to to be deprecated on most platforms according to the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String file paths are outmoded. Use file URLs. And not file URLs derived from a string file path; construct or obtain the URL legitimately. So the real answer is: don't use either of those methods.